# When can I mine Shadmetal Ore?

Tags: tera

I have 204 mining skill and I'm level 32. I tried to mine a Shadmetal Ore in Tera Online, but it says "Your level is too low". It also says (Above Level 40) upon clicking the rock.

Do I actually need to be over level 40 to mine Shadmetal rocks?

Comment: I recomend that you don't mine yet. I tried it by waiting until level 65 and then I mine whatever I might need (usually, goblu essense and pilka silk). This allowed me to do 2 things: get more time to level up and gather the needed ingredients to craft the PVP set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, level requirement for gathering was added on patch 29.03.02, [source](http://tera.enmasse.com/news/patch-notes/patch-290302).

> Minimum level requirement for gathering resources has been added.